# How to set Image source to Image in code behind

Tags: image, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm having trouble getting the `Source` of my `Image` set in the code-behind. Here's my XAML:

```
        <StackPanel Name="stkPanel" Height="1200" Width="478" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.723,0.509">
            <Image Loaded="imgPicture_Loaded_1" x:Name="imgPicture"   ImageOpened="ImgSelectedPicture_ImageOpened_1" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="309" Width="413" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
```

And the code-behind:

```
 private void imgPicture_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgPict = (sender as Image);
        //ScrollViewer scroll = this.LayoutRoot.Children[2] as ScrollViewer;
        
        imgPict.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/project;component/Images/avatar.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        //bindPicture(imgPict);
        

    }
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `BuildAction` of image you want to display is set to Resource? The way you are initializing the image `Uri` is suitable for embedded resources. And the best practice is to use `Content` as `BuildAction` for images and `Uri` initialization will look like `new Uri("/Images/avatar.png", UriKind.Relative)`.

Comment: Why are you waiting to set the image source? What issue are you trying to work around or avoid?

Answer (score 2):

First, what i don't understand is the image path "/project;component/Images/avatar.png" don't think the ";" sign makes the path valid. This should work for you:

```
<StackPanel Name="stkPanel" Height="1200" Width="478" HorizontalAlignment="Center"                 VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.723,0.509">
           <Image Loaded="imgPicture_Loaded" x:Name="imgPicture"  Stretch="UniformToFill"
             Height="309" Width="413" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"             
             Margin="0,30,0,0"></Image>
 </StackPanel>
```

then in the code behind

```
private void imgPicture_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    imgPicture.Source = new BitmapImage(new 
                          Uri("/Images/StoreLogo.png",UriKind.Relative));                                        
 }
```

You can set the image's "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always".

Comment: The URI format that was being used originally IS valid and allows referencing resources in different assemblies. Unless you're doing something unusual after you've built your XAP file there is no value in setting the "Copy to Output Directory" property. It doesn't impact the XAP file. It's there as a hang over from other, older project types where you may want the entire contents of the build/bin directory.